# How do I check if table names are valid in Propel?

Tags: php, mysql, propel

I want to check if a table name is valid in Propel, and then do something with it such as get its PHP name. The problem is that I am using the DatabaseMap and it only contains tables that have been instantiated. For instance:

```
$map = Propel::getDatabaseMap();
$map->getTableName('group'); // throws exception
```

If I iterate over the tables:

```
$tables = $map->getTables();
foreach ($tables as $key => $value) {
    echo $key;
}
```

It only outputs 'user'. It does not output any other tables in my database.

Are there any other methods to check if a table name is valid in Propel?

Comment: Would I have to somehow bootstrap my database's table listing at the beginning of runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse your schema.xml with PHP's simplexml.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('schema.xml');
$tableExists = 0 < count($xml->xpath("table[@phpName='$tableName']"));
```

Don't forget to filter users's input for `$tableName`, otherwise it's possible to inject own query into xpath.
To have better performance you should cache your results.

Even better would be if you create a hash map with all tables based on your `schema.xml`, cache this hash map and check against this every time.

```
$hashMap = $foo->getCache('tables');

if (!$hashMap) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('schema.xml');
    $tables = $xml->xpath("table");
    foreach ($tables as $table) {
        $hashMap[$table['phpName']] = true;
    }
    $foo->setCache('tables', $hashMap);
}

$tableExists = isset($hashMap[$tableName]);
```

In this case it's not really necessary to filter user's input.

Comment: I posted [an issue for Propel 1](https://github.com/propelorm/Propel/issues/819) that would easily solve this issue if the generator simply creates a mapping of table name to PHP names and saves it in a new file, but until or if that's implemented, this is the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could just check to see if the class exists:

```
if (class_exists(camel_case($table, true) . 'Query')) {
  // it exists!
}
```

Comment: Good idea but you have my issue backwards. I needed to convert table names to PHP names, not PHP names to table names.