# Propel - retrieve all tables

Tags: php, oop, orm, propel

I would like to have an output of all schema tables using propel.  When referencing to a particular `TableMap`

```
$users = UsersTableMap::getTableMap();
$map = $users->getDatabaseMap();
$tables = $map->getTables(); //yields an object, holds only Users table
```

Is there a way **not** to use a particular table (e.g. `Users`) but have a more general approach? There is a bit outdated [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22382027/get-the-name-of-all-the-tables-on-my-database) that faces the same problem.

Should I make a custom query or parse the `schema.xml` to retrieve all tables?

### Update

Some of the solutions given below as answers produce empty array

```
$map = Propel::getServiceContainer()->getDatabaseMap(); //w & w/o string argument
$tables = $map->getTables(); //an empty array
```

Comment: It procudes an empty array, because you would need to initialise all TableMaps beforehand, which is very slow if you have many and memory hungry. Better parse just the .schema.xml

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no way in the current version 2 to retrieve all table maps with one call. Why: We would need to load all table maps which is incredible slow and we have no total "map"/"array" listing with all available table maps that was available at buildtime. In Propel3 however, this is possible.

The only solution you should follow is parsing the schema.xml: [How do I check if table names are valid in Propel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21052889/how-do-i-check-if-table-names-are-valid-in-propel/21419866#21419866)

What you can additional do is to reverse the real database using the reverse classes of Propel. However, this is very slow as it will read all the time the whole database structure. See https://github.com/propelorm/Propel2/issues/261#issuecomment-40659647

Comment: Seems like there is no other option. Is something similar provisioned in future releases?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
<?php
use Propel\Runtime\Propel;

$map = Propel::getServiceContainer()->getDatabaseMap('default');
$tables = $map->getTables();
```

`default` should be replaced with whatever name you defined for your database connection.

Answer (score 0):

you can access the db map by obtaining the current propel service container, eg:

```
$dbMap = Propel::getServiceContainer()->getDatabaseMap();
$tables = $dbMap->getTables();
```

Specifically the code abowe will extract the db map from the default connection, but you can specify another connection configured, let's assume you have a secondary connection called "asdrubale":

```
$dbMap = Propel::getServiceContainer()->getDatabaseMap('asdrubale');
$tables = $dbMap->getTables();
```